# Find combination of two list in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists:

```
List1:
123 
456 
789 

List2:
321
654
987
```

I want to find the combination of the 2 lists in a data frame but without combinations inside the lists:

```
123-321
123-654
123-987
456-321
456-654
456-987
789-321
789-654
789-987
321-123
321-456
321-789
654-123
654-456
654-789
987-123
987-456
987-789
```

With these combinations I want to check whether they are inside two columns of a data frame and if yes, extract the rows:

```
A   B   Value
123 321 0.5
456 111 0.4
987 654 0.3

Return:
A   B   Value
123 321 0.5
```

How can I extract the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a cross merge between two columns constructed from the two lists. Then check the existence of `df` `A, B` columns in that merges dataframe with numpy broadcasting.

```py
a = [123, 456, 789]
b = [321, 654, 987]

m = pd.DataFrame({'A': a}).merge(pd.DataFrame({'B': b}), how='cross').to_numpy()[:, None] == df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy()
out = df[m.all(axis=-1).any(axis=0)]
```

```
print(out)

     A    B  Value
0  123  321    0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

a = [123,456,789]
b = [321, 654, 987]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [123, 456, 987], 'B': [321,111,654], 'value': [0.5, 0.4, 0.3]
})


print(df[(df.A.isin(a) & df.B.isin(b) & ~df.A.isin(b) & ~df.B.isin(a)) | (df.A.isin(b) & df.B.isin(a) & ~df.A.isin(a) & ~df.B.isin(b))])
```

Returns:

```
     A    B  value
0  123  321    0.5
```

it works by using a boolean mask, that checks that either:

- column A is in list a, but not in list b and column B is in list b but in in list a
- or the other way around

Comment: why do you check whether column A is in list a, but not in list b? (why the negative condition?) If the lists have no common values, then it is useless, and if they do have `753` in common (for instance), why would `753-753` not be allowed? it is part of the Cartesian product described by OP in their question

Comment: Because OP asked to avoid combinations of the same list, so one entry of one list being in both columns.